# How do I upload an image of an R plot without losing its quality?

Tags: support, images

In my questions about ggplot2, I have to upload the plots.

In order to do so, I copy the plot to [Paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint_%28software%29) and save it as JPEG (I tried to save the plots as PNG, but the size was large, and I couldn't upload it).

Although I can see the plot clearly on my PC, the quality is reduced after uploading it, and I can't see it as clearly anymore as shown below.

[image]

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to upload the plot with high quality to be seen clearly without increasing its size.

Comment: A 24-bit PNG of this is only 500kB, an 8-bit PNG is smaller than the JPEG, so it must have been something other than file size that was keeping you from uploading the PNG.

Comment: Would it be possible to generate an SVG of the plot?  If so, you should be able to use a stack snippet to display it (provided it isn't ridiculously huge).

Comment: That's not one plot, that's five.  Save as high quality PNG, split it, then add all images.

Comment: Maybe worth trying to [copy to clipboard with the right size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295525/copy-r-plot-to-clipboard-with-custom-size) before pasting in Paint - then save as PNG.

Comment: [rstudio](http://rstudio.com/) allows easy export of R plots. Just click export > save as image. The default format is png.

Answer (score 57):

[JPEG is notorious for compression like this:](http://lbrandy.com/blog/2008/10/my-first-and-last-webcomic/)

[image]

<sup>(image from the link above)</sup>

Since JPEG encourages compression like this, the uploader takes advantage of it.

I'd recommend splitting the plots up into individual PNG images (one plot per image, instead of five per image) and adding those to your post.

I'd recommend *not* using another image hosting provider - some providers have been known to replace low-traffic images with advertisements to save hard drive space. Because Stack Exchange is directly involved, `i.stack.imgur` is the most stable thing we have.

Comment: As an addition to your answer (as your are obviously not an R user), the `ggplot2` package has a built it function to do just this called `ggsave`, so one can easily save his plot in a `png` (or `pdf`) format by something like `qplot(length, data = movies, geom = "histogram") ; ggsave("length-hist.png")`. This function also allows you to set `height`, `width`, `scale` and the `dpi`.

Comment: Edited to point to the original source, thanks @Air

Comment: That's one plot with panels, not several plots. OP should not split it.

Comment: JPEG artefacts are only part of the story, though important. Most of the blurriness seems to come from the scaling done by the browser to fit in in the question/answer viewport.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep the plots in a single PNG, there are many online PNG compression tools (e.g. [Compressor.io](https://compressor.io/)) as well as desktop applications (e.g. [PngOptimizer](http://psydk.org/pngoptimizer)) that can help decrease the size of your PNGs so that you can upload them via the built-in uploader. You won't lose image quality using these tools, but the file size can drop drastically.

Comment: Keep in mind that some of the compression settings on some of these tools can cause compression to take a long time, so start with the default settings.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be to start by using something other than Paint to save the images - another software that lets you set the compression level.

As said in other comments, uploading five separate images would be a good idea.

Firstly some generic advice:

But the issue here isn't the just the format - it's the compression ratio that's the issue. Try downloading some free image software like the [GNU Image Manipulation Program](https://www.gimp.org/).

saving the file as Jpeg from such software will allow you to alter the compression level - JPEG specifically does have a "[lossless/near lossless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG)" compression level - perfect for detailed images such as those you are presenting, SO might (I say **might** respect that compression).
Also, when saving as PNG from GIMP you can again, specify compression levels - thus making smaller PNG files (though possibly lossy).

Reccomendation - GIF:

That said, you may find using the [**GIF** format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF) worth trying (it is pretty much designed for these kind of images), GIMP also allows for export in GIF format - It has exceptional compression ratio for a lossless image type.

Note that it is a common misconception that GIF image's are purely for animation - the formats original application was for graphs, diagrams, drawings. IE: exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

Other option you have, in case you want to "upload" the image is to embed a link to a generated SVG of your plot.

**Pros:**

- There will be no quality loss at all.
- You won't have to worry about the size limit of your image, as it will be hosted outside SO (e.g. http://imgh.us)

**Cons:**

- You will require to upload your image to a different server than SO (http://imgh.us, https://imgur.com/, http://www.deviantart.com/, etc)

If you decide this suits your needs,

Wrap your R code with:

```
svg("normal_distribution.svg",width=7,height=7)
... R code ...
dev.off()
```

For example,

```
svg("normal_distribution.svg",width=7,height=7)
s <- seq(10, 9234500, by=runif(1, 4, 199))
y <- rnorm(s)
hist(y, prob=T, col=c('cornflowerblue'), border = F)
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(y), sd=sd(y)), add=T, col=c('black'))
dev.off()
```

Then upload the generated `normal_distribution.svg` file to for example,[imgh.us](https://web.archive.org/web/20190709123510/http://imgh.us/)

Finally when the [file](https://imgh.us/normal_distribution_1.svg) is updated and you have the link, add this html to your SO post:

`<img src="https://imgh.us/normal_distribution_1.svg"/>`

You are done, edit this post to see the code.

[image]

Link to the image [here](https://imgh.us/normal_distribution_1.svg)

Comment: It is true that a vector format is preferable for this type of plots. Unfortunately, the OP is trying to display the images in the post, and not only link to a file, so he is limited in the formats he can use by the browsers.

Comment: I don't see much point in using vectors for a plot that consists mainly of scattered single pixels.

Comment: Your final two paragraphs are dead wrong.  PNG is specifically a Rasterized format which uses `Lossless` compression, and BMP is also lossless (because it does no compression).  A vector format *does* have the advantage that is can be scaled arbitrarily (which may be what you were thinking of), and for many images it will be more compact.  However, looking at these plots, I would be surprised if a vector format was smaller than PNG.

Comment: The goal is to display the images inline. These sites don't support displaying PDFs inline.

Comment: Why not use a stack snippet with the SVG?  That way it can be hosted on-site.

Answer (score 0):

Others have noted the inadequacy of JPEG for graphs and charts, with PNG the superior format, and there are a number of ways to get your ouput in that format (even in Paint). These questions are better suited to the main site though.

However, what is important to note is that once you upload the image, it needs to fit into the question and answer part of the page. This scales with the available device size or window but is at most **675 pixels wide**. If your image is wider, the browser will scale it. Different browsers may perform better than others. The scaling usually works best when it is an integer multiple (eg 2x, 3x, etc).

You can either produce it in a size which can be scaled more easily by the browser, or rescale the image yoursef to match the site requirements using a decent image editing program (eg GIMP) to avoid browser scaling.